# Git counting too many files and tries to push untracked files

Tags: git, github, command-line

I'm relatively noob with git and guthub. I've run into an issue that prevents me from uploading files to github.

After doing

```
git add .
git commit -m "update"
git push origin master
```

console then says

```
Counting objects: 5439, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3670/3670), done.
^Citing objects:   5% (320/5439), 31.90 MiB | 3.54 MiB/s    
Total 5439 (delta 1392), reused 5438 (delta 1391)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1392/1392), completed with 1 local object.
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large 
File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: 5dd2ad6c7e223707ec5baf451b28c2f0
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File ImmerGo_24x2/ImmerGo node server + 
client/nwjs.app/Contents/Versions/56.0.2924.87/nwjs Framework.framework/nwjs 
Framework is 101.72 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

5439 is waaay too many files, it would seem it is trying to upload my nw.app aswell, even though I have left this untracked. I've also included it's path in my .gitignore.

After running these

```
git ls-files
git ls-files --others
```

It would seem that it is tracking the correct files for my repo, so I'm not sure how to prevent the client/nwjs.app from being uploaded aswell.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The output suggests a path of **ImmerGo_24x2/ImmerGo node server + client/nwjs.app/**... but in text you refer to just **client/nwjs.app**.  Are these two different paths, or i the latter a shorthand, or...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Describing the problem

This:

> ```
> Counting objects: 5439, done.
> ```

is a count of *objects*, not files.  Git has four kinds of objects: commits, trees, blobs (loosely "files"), and (annotated) tags.  So this means there are 5439 commits-plus-trees-plus-blobs-plus-tags in the set of objects you are telling your Git to send to their (GitHub's) Git.

> ```
> git ls-files
> ```

The `ls-files` command displays the files (blob objects) stored in the *index*.  The index is not a commit (but is *related to* a commit: it's where your Git builds your *next* commit).

When you run `git push`, you instruct your Git to call up another Git.  They negotiate which "top level objects" (commits and/or tags, generally) your Git should send to their Git, based on the *refspec* arguments you supply:

`git push remote refspec1 refspec2 ... refspecN`

In your case the *remote* is `origin` (i.e., GitHub's Git) and the single refspec was `master`.  So your Git looks at which commit your `master` identifies, and which commit *their* `master` identifies.  Your Git finds all the commits that you have, that they don't.

This is almost certainly at least *two* commits, and probably more.

Your Git then packages up all of those commits, and all of the other objects—trees and blobs—that those commits *use*, that their Git doesn't already have.  That's where the `5439` object count comes from.  There are enough commits, trees, and blobs in the set you're sending, to add up to that many objects.

Once their Git has received all those objects, their Git unpacks them and (via a pre-receive or update hook, no doubt) inspects them.  One of those commits has a large file in it.  Their Git then rejects the request to update their `master`, after printing the error message you see (your Git prefixes each line with the word `remote:` before printing it).

#### Solving the problem

You'll need to push different (maybe fewer and/or better) commits.

To do this, you need—well, "want"—to make your `master` point to new, different commits.  You can then abandon your old (and ugly?) commits, or keep them on a branch you never push to GitHub.  Whether to keep or abandon them is up to you.

There are many ways to accomplish this, and I have too little time to write about them again right now.  Look up *rebasing* and "the BFG".  Depending on whether you want to use BFG (it's reportedly much simpler), you can also use `git filter-branch`, but it's complicated.  If you have an easy case—it's impossible to tell from what you've posted here—a simple `git rebase -i origin/master` and converting commits of removals of prior accidental commits of big files into `squash`es may suffice.